# Pirating books, taboo?

Tags: discussion, ethics

Is it alright to speak about pirated books in writers SE? This is a controversial subject I am not sure how to approach the issue.

For instance, when my interest in potentially being a professional writer was rekindled, I downloaded over 5GB worth (thousands) of writing books. [...content edited...]

Comment: you VTC your own question? Then why did you ask it the first place?

Comment: @Ooker Because although it was answered, it continued to generate comments on pirating ethics...You don't see the answer because my full Q,,and comments were edited out, also it was empirically answered when i tried recommending bundles of pirated books....  the short answer is No, it's not ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to recommend a book, recommend a book. How and where a user obtains a book is irrelevant to what this site is about.

I have argued elsewhere on this site that reading how-to books can be a sign of procrastination and an obstacle to actually writing your book. Recommending a download (and possible reading) of hundreds of books seems counterproductive to me.

Finally, as a writer, I respect the wish of a fellow writer to be paid for his work.

Comment: That is so true; there is a balancing act required. Reading all of them for fear of missing something vital, can be a delaying tactic. Yet, I have seen many aspiring authors, who didn’t read a single one, and were clueless about premise, rising conflict, or climax.

Comment: i want to delete this Question, but i feel your answer is valuable vis a vis procrastination. can you copy your answer to a new Q/A or possibly as an add on to the older Q you are refering to.